# Face Recognition using google mlkit on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-mlkit, tflite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Izne.jpg)I am trying to developing a face recognizing app in flutter.The problem is ,that i couldn't detect
faces when changning the device orientation to landscape mode.But in potrait mode it work fine.

link: https://github.com/maneesh8123/https---github.com-maneesh8123-Realtime-Face-Recognition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUzH4.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJRaR.jpg)

Comment: I think the link is broken, could you please fix it

Comment: Link Not Work / No Any Code For Reproduce.

Comment: Now  link is available.Can you please check it..